# jestjs throw error as ` TypeError: _App.default is not a constructor`

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

here is my class file in 'App.js'

```
import CardList from './CardList';

 export default class App {

    constructor() {
        this.cards = [];
        this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this);
    }

    addCard(data) {
        this.cards = [...this.cards, data];
        CardList(this.cards);
    }
}
```

My Spec file :

```
import App from './App';

describe('app tests goes here', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {})

})
```

But as soon as I run the test 'yarn test', getting an error as:

```
  TypeError: _App.default is not a constructor

      3 |
      4 |
    > 5 | const app = new App();
        |             ^
```

how to fix this? what is the issue here? any one help me to understand please?

my spec file: I am not yet to start to work..

```
import App from './App';

describe('app tests goes here', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {})

})
```

Comment: could you please add the `Spec` file code as well .

Comment: @Sohail - added my test file. But I am not start to work on it at all

Comment: Where are you using this code `const app = new App();`

Comment: I have tried the same code on my local and it's working fine, I think there is some setup issue.

Comment: @Sohail - `const app = new App();` in `index.js` file. I am using `webpack` is it require any additional configs?

Comment: Is this react app or just vanilla javascript app ?

Comment: if the `new App()` is defined in `index.js` file then why jest is calling `index` file. I don't see index file included in app.js or in specs file.

Comment: that's what i am confusion. can you have a look over here : https://github.com/3gwebtrain/webpack-jsapp